# html5 video 'ended' event on android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, html5-video, jquery-events

I'm developing a web page intended for use on mobile devices, primarily Pandigital tablets running Android. On this page I have an html5 video element that plays upon page load, and when the video ends I need to have a Javascript function trigger and hide the video element. So far I have a basic multipage document set up with jQuery mobile just to test whether I can even get a trigger to work. The function I'm using is:

```
pageInit(function(){
$("#vid1").bind('ended', function(){
$.mobile.changePage($('#two'), 'fade');
});
});
```

The video (with a proper `id="vid1"`) pops into fullscreen and plays perfectly. However, the page doesn't change when the video is finished playing. I am testing using Android 2.3.4.